# mysql Group by X and show Total1 (when Field = 0 of the same table) and Total2 (when Field = 1)

Tags: mysql

I have this query that return as the image show :

```
SELECT a.idarticle, c.stock, a.libelle as 'Libelle', sum(a.price * o.quantity) as `Total` from command c
inner join store s on c.idstore = s.idstore
inner join operation o on c.idcommand = o.idcommand
inner join article a on o.idarticle = a.idarticle
group by o.idarticle, c.stock
```

[image]

I would like to have like : ID, Libelle, Total1 (when stock = 0), Total2 (when stock=1)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT a.idarticle, a.libelle as `Libelle`, 
        sum(if(a.stock=0,a.price * o.quantity, 0)) `Total0`,
        sum(if(a.stock=1,a.price * o.quantity, 0)) `Total1`,
      --sum(a.price * o.quantity) as `Total` 
  from command c
  inner join store s on c.idstore = s.idstore
  inner join operation o on c.idcommand = o.idcommand
  inner join article a on o.idarticle = a.idarticle
  group by a.idarticle, a.stock;
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to make some adaptation and this is my working query for anyone else :

[code]SELECT a.idarticle, a.libelle as `Libelle`, 
        sum(if(c.stock=0,a.price * o.quantity, 0)) `Total0`,
        sum(if(c.stock=1,a.price * o.quantity, 0)) `Total1`,
      --sum(a.price * o.quantity) as `Total` 
  from command c
  inner join store s on c.idstore = s.idstore
  inner join operation o on c.idcommand = o.idcommand
  inner join article a on o.idarticle = a.idarticle
  group by a.idarticle;[/code]

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a.idarticle, a.libelle as 'Libelle', 
sum(case when stock = 0 then a.price * o.quantity) as `Total1` ,
sum(case when stock = 1 then a.price * o.quantity) as `Total2` 
from command c
inner join store s on c.idstore = s.idstore
inner join operation o on c.idcommand = o.idcommand
inner join article a on o.idarticle = a.idarticle
group by a.idarticle, a.libelle
```